# When 'SELECT'ing with partition key is the seek time in Cassandra constant or linear?

Tags: cassandra

If Cassandra hashes the partition key, can it reach the queried partition in constant time? Or does it need to iterate through all the partitions?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. @Schildmeijer
Is there a detailed documentation about this topic?

Comment: Google "consistent hashing" and you will get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant.

Cassandra is essentially a giant hash map.